# Can't make font-weight work how do i make it work?

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I can't get the font I am using to load in different weights.

I've tried loading in all the different weights from google fonts and both trying the @import within my css and the

In my css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800');

* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.titles{
    align-content:left;
    font-weight:800;
}
```

In my html:

```
<div class="titles">
   <h2> What we do.</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 800 value is overruled by the default browser setting of 700 for `h2` elements since you only applied it to `.titles`. You need to apply `font-weight: 800` specifically to the `h2` element.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800');

* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.titles h2 {
    align-content: left;
    font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<div class="titles">
    <h2>What we do.</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use link in head tag of your html :)

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

Be careful so you don't split the `import` link into multiple rows and also check for spaces in the link. It should all be on one line. No spaces or breaklines.

`@import` should be used if you have different style sheets and you just need that import in a specific stylesheet. Or if you don't have access to edit the `<head>` element.

Else, you should use the html `<link>` element to include your fonts directly in the `head` element.

Check below

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800');

 * {
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }

 .titles {
   align-content: left;
   font-weight: 800;
 }
```

```html
<div class="titles">
  <h2> What we do.</h2>
</div>
```